# Using dpkg to install upgrade and dist-upgrade packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

So I'm playing around with offline package installation on 12.04 Server, having downloaded packages by retrieving and wgetting their URIs using the instructions here: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/get-list-of-packages-and-dependencies.html

I did this with `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, then went about installing the downloaded packages using `dpkg -i`. So the process looked like so:

1. Get URIs
2. `wget` the packages to a folder (`upgrade` packages to /upgrade and `dist-upgrade` packages to /dist-upgrade)
3. run `dpkg -i /upgrade/*.deb` and then `dpkg -i /dist-upgrade/*.deb`

My question is: would this method of manually installing the updated packages correctly get everything updated, giving the same result as if I'd just run `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` normally?
Or is there something that the normal `apt-get` commands do that wouldn't get done with this way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using `dpkg`, which is a low level package manager, you'd be better off using `apt`. To install the .deb files using `apt`, copy them to the apt cache

```
sudo cp *.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

and then just do the regular upgrade:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

The `apt` command will use the files in its cache rather than downloading it off the net, so that pretty much serves your purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Though I'm still curious about what exactly `apt` does differently to `dpkg` in this case, given I originally used `apt` to get the URIs of all the packages, including their dependencies? When it comes to the actual act of installation it looks like `apt` is pretty much just using `dpkg` to perform the unpacking and installation of the packages, the only difference being that `apt` checks for dependencies beforehand (but that's already covered because I used `apt` to download the packages, including dependencies, in the first place). Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Also, part of the reason I ask is that I'm concerned about what `apt's` behaviour might be if, say, the downloaded packages were copied onto a system that had Internet access and then `apt` sees that some or all of the downloaded packages are not the latest (but newer than what's currently installed) and then it rather tries to get the updated versions of those particular packages (I want it to install only the specific packages/versions that I've downloaded). Basically, does `apt` give preference to the latest online version or will it give preference to a local, newer-but-not-latest version?

Comment: @R4mzy You've got a valid point there. `apt` will try to get the latest package from the internet, even if there are older packages available locally. You might need to change `/etc/apt/sources.list` t make sure it installs the local packages.

Comment: @sayantankhan can you show what that would look like in your answer? I am asking because I've copied my .deb file to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` doesnt see it or update/upgrade the package I need. I feel like I need to update the list but am not sure how.

Comment: @Todd I haven't done it myself, but [here](http://www.linuxwave.info/2009/04/adding-local-directory-to-apt.html) is a way someone overrode the apt package priority.