# Updating a package using a .deb?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, virtualbox

I´m using ubuntu 12.04 LTS (precise/amd64), I have installed virtualbox-4.3, I was forced to install it with a downloaded package (.deb) because I could not download it normally, I used "Free Download Manager" to download it because the speed was horrible (50KB/s and stuck everytime), and today I was doing `apt-get update/upgrade` and have a update for virtualbox.

First, I want to know if I download the `virtualbox-4.3_4.3.12-93733~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb` and use the `dpkg -i` it will update the package without overwriting my settings (or not).

Second, I want to know if is just with me this problem that is so slow the speed (In all computers in my network).

I found a similar question here: [Using dpkg to install upgrade and dist-upgrade packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372153/using-dpkg-to-install-upgrade-and-dist-upgrade-packages).

I think this will solve my problem, I will test and after I will post if it worked.

Comment: Is the package from virtualbox or ubuntu repositories?

Comment: No it is in virtualbox repository, http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/pool/contrib/v/virtualbox-4.3/

Answer (score 0):

I install from virtualbox site and the update installs without overwriting my files.

If there is a major update a message will come up that says you have to remove the old virtualbox before installing the new update then I click to remove virtualbox and install the new updated version and it still keeps my settings and vm's as long as I do not choose to remove the configuration files.

The updated file you posted is the same as the one on virtualbox and it is a .deb file just install using software center and you should not have any problems.